# Invalid header cookie when integrate twitter in android

Tags: android, twitter

I've integrated Twitter for Android using [this tutorial](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/)

It used to run normally, but suddenly it started showing the following error:

> 05-23 23:17:12.492: W/ResponseProcessCookies(17376): Invalid cookie
>   header: "set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A136932583219426033;
>   Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 23-May-2015 16:17:12 UTC".
>   Unable to parse expires attribute: Sat, 23-May-2015 16:17:12 UTC

After showing the login page in a browser and starting to login, it shows an authorize page. When I try to authorize from this page, I am not returned to my application like I expected. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'va has solution for this , actually it because my android device has malware , so I try to scan with antivirus and try again , and it works :)

Comment: I have restored all settings in my devices and erased everything in it.but still doesnt work..

Comment: try to scan your device with antivirus

Comment: Did that with AVG.But of no use.

Comment: it worked when i changed the twitter4j library from 2.x.x to 3.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

Your expires needs to be in the format:

```
Sat, 23 May 2015 16:17:12 GMT
```

Lose the dashes and your TZ needs to be GMT.

Assuming that you are using SimpleDateFormat, this is equivalent to the format string:

```
"EEE,  d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
```

To set the timezone to GMT:

```
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Comment: how to change that expires?? :(

Comment: I mean where I can setting that?? because Im newbie in android , and I just follow this tutorial http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/ to integrate twitter in android app

Comment: All I can do is give you the why it is not working. I'm not going to go through the code of a tutorial to tell you where the problem is (that's not what StackOverflow is for). You should contact the tutorial creator and ask them to correct it or use this as a learning exercise in tracing and debugging.

Comment: You ever integrate twitter for android??

Comment: Yes, but that was code written for a client and I cannot share that with you (the contract was that the client owns that code).

Comment: The poster is not the one generating the string. It is Twitter that is returning the date as the expiration for the cookie.