# I am not able to implement twitter ,showing some migration error in android

Tags: android, twitter, android-twitter

While implementing twitter i am getting migration error .Please any one help to solve this problem.

**{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}**

Comment: Twitter has discontinued usage of API v1 last weeek. Change your API to v1.1 !

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084074/how-to-migrate-twitter-api-from-v1-to-v1-1