# Migrate Twitter API from v1 to v1.1 in Android

Tags: android, twitter

I tried to working with twitter integration in android. I used twitter4j jar for doing this. while posted into twitter I got this error.

```
{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}
```

So, I followed this link for solving myproblem: [How to Migrate Twitter API from v1 to v1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084074/how-to-migrate-twitter-api-from-v1-to-v1-1)

It was fine, but in my code I tried to post image into twitter. Below line code of  my class was not supported:

```
OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(conf, conf.getOAuthConsumerKey(), conf.getOAuthConsumerSecret(), new AccessToken(conf.getOAuthAccessToken(), conf.getOAuthAccessTokenSecret()));
                ImageUpload upload = ImageUpload.getTwitpicUploader (com.cpt.realtor.socialsharing.SocialSharingConstants.TWITPIC_APP_KEY, auth);
```

How can I solve this, by Migrating from v1 to v1.1

Comment: Which version of Twitter Jar file are you using?

Comment: Use latest Version of that I am using Twitter4j 3.0.3 It will be good for you

Comment: I Updated from twitter4j-core-2.1.6 to twitter4j-core-3.0.3, then only those two classes are  not supported.

Comment: Yeah,,, that two classes are in different Package in Twitter4j 3.0.3 so do one thing delete all imported files in your class and then do Ctrl+Shift+O so that classes will be imported.

Comment: Is there any different from Twitter4j-3.0.3.jar to Twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar or both are same

Comment: they are same sorry for not writing Core.

Comment: I did same process.. still not supported those two classes. Please give solution for this..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36639/discussion-between-lokesh-and-mdroid)

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084074/how-to-migrate-twitter-api-from-v1-to-v1-1