# How to get Tweets from Twitter of perticular User in Android ?(Want to show tweets(Done by signin User) in my list view)

Tags: android, twitter4j

I am integrating Twitter with my android Application for that I am using **Twitter4j 3.0.3**. till now everything is fine I have completed composing new Tweet,Upload Image,change profile picture. Now I want to **show Tweets(composed by Signin User)** .

For that I have used following tutorial and links

[link 1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline)

[link 2](http://www.sitepoint.com/loading-twitter-data-into-android-with-lists/)

[link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454357/how-to-get-latest-tweets-in-my-listview)

But I am not fully satisfied with these,I have tried one demo also but I am getting error of

```
    Invalid cookie
    header: “set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A136932583219426033;
    Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 23-May-2015 16:17:12 UTC”.
    Unable to parse expires attribute: Sat, 23-May-2015 16:17:12 UTC
```

I tried to find out solution but I have found same solution everywhere like

[Cookie Header](https://dev.twitter.com/issues/%5Bfield_issue_id-id%5D)

[same issue like mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719134/invalid-header-cookie-when-integrate-twitter-in-android)

they have shown the solution but I cant figure out where should I change in my code?

So I **need one good example for Showing Tweets**(which is done by User)in list view I have tried most examples as shown above, but I am getting error **Invalid cookie
header:** so please **explain me in detail** how should I fix these error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get Answer of My Question :)

Here it is .. :)

```
btn_getTweets.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                tweets_list.clear();
                TwitterLogin.mTwitter.getUserTweets();
                if(tweets_list.size()==0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You haven't tweeted yet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    tweetsAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tweets_list);
                    listView.setAdapter(tweetsAdapter);
                }

            }
        });
```

where  `TwitterLogin.mTwitter` class has store my Credentials.
and  `TwitterLogin.mTwitter.getUserTweets()` is method is in other class Like

```
public void getUserTweets(){
        System.out.println("Showing public timeline.");
        try {
            List<Status> statuses = mTwitter.getUserTimeline();
            for (Status status : statuses) {
                System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":"
                        + status.getText());
             ComposeTwit.tweets_list.add(""+ status.getText());
            }
            Log.d("tweets_list Size", ""+ComposeTwit.tweets_list.size());
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            System.out.println("Failed to get timeline: "
                    + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: recently they have upgraded the api from version1. How u managed that?

Comment: Hii..Sorry for being late.. I am using Twitter4j

Comment: {"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}

Comment: Are you using Twiiter4j 3.0.3?? If not then use latest jar.

Comment: twitter4j-3.0.4-SNAPSHOT